# How to check iCloud free space

Tags: swift, iphone, storage, backup, icloud

I want to upload my app data on iCloud but my iCloud storage has no space.
How can I check for that so I can show alert before start uploading?

Answer (score -1):

To see how much you currently have, 
1, Open the Settings app, select “iCloud”, and find where it says “Storage” to view how much space you have left in your iCloud account.
2, You can also view your available iCloud storage space by navigating to “General” > “Storage & iCloud Usage”.

Comment: I think you do not answer the question, he probably asks how to do it in code, not how to navigate in the iOS.